# Show only one category

Tags: categories, php

I have this code to show cathegory like image:

```
<?php 
foreach((get_the_category()) as $cat)
{
    $catname =$cat->category_nicename;
    echo "<a href=\"/category/";
    echo $catname;
    echo "/\">";
    echo "<img src=\"/wp-content/categorias/";
    echo $catname;
    echo ".png\" alt=\"$catname category image\" /></a>\n";
}
?>
```

The problem is: I want to show only one category by post because I have a lot of posts with more than one category. I want to show only one category.

Answer (score 2):

### CHRISTMAS EDITION

Due to Christmas time and my brain hitting some serious technical difficulties, I got `get_the_category()` and `get_the_categories` filter mixed up.

Here is the revised filter function, working:

You can also make use of the [`get_the_categories` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_the_categories/)

```
add_filter( 'get_the_categories', function ( $categories )
{
    // Only return the first object in the array
    return $cat[] = $categories[0];
});
```

### ORIGINAL ANSWER

Because you pass everything directly to your `foreach` loop, the easiest ist to `break` the loop after the first iteration

```
<?php 
foreach((get_the_category()) as $cat)
{
    $catname =$cat->category_nicename;
    echo "<a href=\"/category/";
    echo $catname;
    echo "/\">";
    echo "<img src=\"/wp-content/categorias/";
    echo $catname;
    echo ".png\" alt=\"$catname category image\" /></a>\n";

    // Lets break the loop after one iteration
    break;
}
?>
```

Comment: You don't even need that `if`, just break at the end of the loop ;)

Comment: @TheDeadMedic ya, thanks for that reminder. Seems I was trying to get to clever again here ;-)